# Matplotlib plot shows 2 labels on the y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to generate a continously generated plot in matplotlib. The problem that I am facing is related to the labelling on the right y-axis. The range that shows is my desired, however there is also an additional set off labels (0, 0.2, ... 1,0).

```
def doAnimation():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    def animate(i):
        data=prices(a,b,c)  #this gives a DataFrame with 2 columns (value 1 and 2)

        plt.cla()
        ax.plot(data.index, data.value1)
        ax2 = ax.twinx()
        ax2.plot(data.index, data.value2)
        plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()     
        plt.tight_layout()  
        return ax, ax2

    call = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, 1000)  
    return call

callSave = doAnimation()
plt.show()
```

Any ideas how can I get rid of the set: 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0?

This is how the graph looks:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`plt.cla`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.cla.html) clears the current axes. The first time you call `plt.cla`, the current axes are `ax` (`ax2` doesn't exist yet). Clearing these axes resets both the x and y range of `ax` to (0,1). However, on line 8, you plot to `ax`, and both ranges are appropriately adjusted.

On line 9, you create a *new* set of axes and call them `ax2`. When you leave  the `animate` function, the name `ax2` will go out of scope, but the axes object to which it refers will persist. These axes are now the current axes.

The second time you call animate, `plt.cla` clears those axes, resetting the x and y range to (0,1). Then, on line 9, you create a *new* set of axes and call them `ax2`. *These axes are not the same axes as before!* `ax2` in fact refers to a third set of axes, which will be cleared the next time you call `plt.cla`. Each new call to animate makes a new set of axes. The offending axes labels appear to be bolded; in fact, they have been drawn a thousand times.

The simplest (fewest changes) fix would be to move `ax2 = ax.twinx()` outside  of `animate`, and replace `plt.cla` with separate calls to `ax.cla` and `ax2.cla`.

I think a better approach would be to create the lines outside of `animate`, and modify their data within `animate`. While we're at it, let's replace those references to `plt.gcf()` with references to `fig`, and set `tight_layout` *via* an argument to `plt.subplots`.

Putting said changes together, we get,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def dummy_prices():
    samples = 101
    xs = np.linspace(0, 10, samples)
    ys = np.random.randn(samples)
    zs = np.random.randn(samples) * 10 + 50
    return pd.DataFrame.from_records({'value1': ys, 'value2': zs}, index=xs)


def doAnimation():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, tight_layout=True)
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    ax2 = ax.twinx()

    data = dummy_prices()
    line = ax.plot(data.index, data.value1)[0]
    line2 = ax2.plot(data.index, data.value2, 'r')[0]

    def animate(i):
        data = dummy_prices()
        line.set_data(data.index, data.value1)
        line2.set_data(data.index, data.value2)
        return line, line2

    animator = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=10)
    return animator


def main():
    animator = doAnimation()
    animator.save('animation.gif')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

where `animation.gif` should look something like,

[image: animation.gif]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Great stuff! It works. 
A side question that I would like to raise is whether you know for any good tutorials or docs on matplotlib or how would you recommend me to improve my skills?

Comment: The matplotlib website is in better shape than ever. Start here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html